# JAVA method for Class/Object creation destruction

Tags: java, profiling, btrace

I want to make a btrace script to profile object creation and destruction.
For that I need to know Which Java methods are called when creating or deleting an Object or a Class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For desctruction: finalize()

Comment: method of the class java.lang.Oject ?

Comment: google `Which Java methods are called when creating or deleting an Object or a Class?`

Answer (score 1):

For the object construction you would use the constructor methods

```
@OnMethod(clazz="class.name", method="<init>")
...
```

Tracing destruction is more difficult - you can't hook into the **finalize** method because it is not mandatory for an object to provide one.

Right now you would need to run BTrace in **unsafe mode** and provide your own logic using eg. **PhantomReference** to get notification when an instance will just have been garbage collected ('destructed').